# Git-Bash not running Python3 as expected, hanging issues

Tags: linux, windows-10, python, python3, git-bash

I will try to be as descriptive but brief as possible...

I have been using GitBash in that past on Win10 successfully. I came back to my Windows machine after not using it for a bit and can't seem to get it to launch python scripts it ran without issue previously. I have an alias created for Python3 called py. For instance...

```
$ py --version
Python 3.7.1
```

I can get into the iterator just fine

```
$ py -i
Python 3.7.1 (v3.7.1:260ec2c36a, Oct 20 2018, 14:57:15) [MSC v.1915 64 bit 
(AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

I can run my scripts just fine in the iterator. Exiting with ctrl+z throws an error, however. In conjunction with this error, when I try to run the scipts from the command line, it hangs and does not respond. See below...

```
$ py -i
Python 3.7.1 (v3.7.1:260ec2c36a, Oct 20 2018, 14:57:15) [MSC v.1915 64 bit 
(AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>       0 [sig] bash 5224! sigpacket::process: Suppressing signal 18 to 
win32 process (pid 5160)

>>> exit()

$ py Lottery.py
```

It does nothing from this point, until I hit "Enter", at which time it throws a python error and returns me to my command line. I know the python script to be working. I can post the python error if it is helpful, though I think it is a red-herring and not art of the GitBash issue at hand.

Any ideas as to why GitBash is not playing well while trying run python scripts? Thanks in advance!

Comment: In bash Ctrl-Z stops the current process (you can then use `bg` to make it continue in the background or `fg` to give it back the terminal focus). If you want to stop Python try Ctrl-D.

Answer (score 7):

This is a known issue for windows 10. GitBash's terminal has issues with windows-native apps, such as `python`, `powershell`, `ipython`, etc.

- The terminal eats events, such as your screenshot. This breaks `ctr+c` / `ctrl+z` events, preventing exiting
- In addition, those apps break cursor movement, massively corrupted the shell.

## The solution is to run `winpty`, which you should already have from git-bash. Now git-bash is able to run apps without issues.

```
$ winpty python -i
```

This fixes both `python -i`, `ipython -i`, `powershell`. I use the following aliases:

```
alias ipython='winpty ipython'
alias python='winpty python'
alias node='winpty node'
alias powershell='winpty powershell'
```

## An alternate solution is to use a different terminal, such as `Windows Terminal`

Recently windows released a new [Windows Terminal](https://github.com/microsoft/terminal)

Now it supports all bash apps, full utf-8 support (the best of any Windows terminals I've ever seen, 256+ ANSI colors, etc.) You no longer need `winpty`.

Edit your JSON config to use:

```
"commandline" : "ipython.exe"
```

## If you are using `python -i` at all, check out ipython.

Combine that with `winpty` or the terminal to run `ipython`. It's a huge upgrade to quality of life and usability.

It adds a lot.

- get function signatures and docs using `foo?` and `foo??`
- copy->paste works.
- quality of life using any statements longer than one line are hugely improved
- syntax highlighting, even matches braces
- tab completion of names *and* inspection of attributes such as:

```
x = "hi world"
x.<tab> # all `str` methods pop-up.

# or
import time
time.monotonic?
```

Get it using

```
python -m pip install ipython
```